# How can I get the Digital Signature from dll file, .NET reflection possible?

Tags: digital-signature

the digital signature could be found by, r.click on dll file, or any other file -> select digital signature tab.

How can i do it by c sharp code? 
the reason of this tool is to test that all the files have the signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Authenticode signature of PE format (Windows EXE and DLL files), then you can do this using Authenticode components of [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php). Unfortunately, CAB and CAT file signatures are not supported at the moment.